# phpBB Spambot countermeasures

Tags: registration, recaptcha, spam, phpbb

I am running a forum on phpBB which is updated to the latest version (3.0.11) and in the past I had used reCAPTCHA as a spambot countermeasure. Unfortunately even with that on, I am getting tons of spam fake accounts, a problem which has caused some problems sometimes.

Through googleing I found out that a lot of people were suggesting I used the "Custom Registration Question" as more reliable solution. Although I can create and edit those questions, whenever I change the settings to any other form of countermeasure than reCAPTCHA, I am getting this error:

[image: Forum registration problem]

So for the time being I keep using the reCAPTCHA to keep my forum functional.

Anyone has any idea or any suggestion of what might be the issue or how can I fix it? I tried so far reuploading the ucp_register.php and .html from a clean install but still, I had the same issue. So I don't know what else to do...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm freelancing on phpBB forums, and I'd advise you to try https://www.keycaptcha.com/ - it's cool captcha which uses Flash or HTML5(if Flash isn't supported). User has to complete small jigsaw puzzle with 2-4 pieces. I've already tried it on many boards and it helps a lot. Of course it won't help if some user is spamming, but it throws away all spambots.

Comment: It seems awesome. How do I install it on phpBB?

Comment: Sign up using your E-mail address or Google or Facebook profile. Then use Add new site menu to get API keys and download phpBB Modification. Installation of modification is similar to all other phpBB mods.

Comment: Before advising others I'd have checked the background - who and why finances KeyCAPTCHA service. Most probably it is tracking system. It is impossible to control what it is loading directly into browsers of visitors from its backservers directly. The "protected" site receives only answer about captcha passing

Comment: And you can control what is loading recaptcha and other services? Even simple statistics systems collect detailed information about visitors. Even though it collects some details, it does the job. Just check related box on the right of this page - spam passes recaptcha. Why you are so worried about this? Every service collects information in different ways. And, btw, keycaptcha won a grant from StartFellows, so I think they have some money.